# Fight where opponents multiply themselves by jumping in time

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this around 2000 (± 5 years), so I could have messed up some details.

- I read this around 2000, but as I remember story was older ('60s?).
- The plot was a duel between two humans (wizards? gods?) that had an ability to move in time. They use this ability to multiply themselves to hundreds copies. It was kind of good vs evil duel.
- I think there was some element to suggest that this is happening in the distant future.
- I would give my right arm that it was Roger Zelazny story but I went through [his bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Zelazny_bibliography), and nothing rang any bells (but I read it in polish so I wasn't expecting miracles).

Comment: Poul Anderson's *There Will Be Time*??

Comment: I was thinking of that, but probably not, not many ticks for most of the other comments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_Will_Be_Time

Comment: It's not the answer, but it sounds very similar to Branches on the Tree of Time by Alexander Wales, a fanfiction about Terminator's Skynet and the resistance using those same tactics.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Must be [Creatures of Light and Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creatures_of_Light_and_Darkness) by  Roger Zelazny

MCs use "temporal fugue" to jump back in time, to strike each other.
By doing that multiple times, they present lots of copies of themselves.

> ...The point of initial encounter draws on, as General before General and
> Wakim before Wakim face and fugue.
>
> ...Five minutes and seven seconds of the future stand in abeyance as
> twelve Generals and nine Wakims look upon one another.
>
> ...Five minutes and twenty-one seconds, as nineteen Wakims and fourteen
> Generals glare in frozen striking-stances.
>
> ...The armies of Wakim and the General are also raised by the waves of
> chaos and driven by the winds of change until they, too, are come at
> last to the green gateway which stands now wide, like a luminous
> magnet/ drain/whirlpool’s center. Still striving, they flow toward it,
> and one by one pass within and are gone.

[Online book](https://www.rulit.me/books/creatures-of-light-and-darkness-read-82445-17.html)

Comment: That's the reason I cannot find it ‍♂️It was part of a book.

Answer (score 8):

I think the accepted answer is the best one; but thought I'd point out that there's another oddball Zelazny that sort-of matches: [Psychoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychoshop). Begun by Bester, the novel was completed by Zelazny after Bester's death. It was published in '98, *after Zelazny's death*, with a forward by Greg Bear (who thankfully survived the experience).

Comment: Thank the random factors that at least one author involved in the project survived to see its' completion. 

Comment: And now, sadly, Greg Bear has departed this mortal coil. RIP.

Answer (score 2):

How about "Legions in Time" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legions_in_Time by Michael Swanwick?  It is a brilliant story which very cleverly tells the hidden story behind A. E. Van Vogt's "Recruiting Station".

It ticks all the points raised.  As Wikipedia says, "A widow with the strange job of sitting in an empty office and guarding an empty closet, decides to take action and steps through—and falls into a cosmic, time-spanning adventure that ends with her becoming an entire organization spread throughout time with a goal of destroying the evil Empire of the Aftermen."

Published 2003 (Check). But based heavily on a well-known 1942 story (Check for old time connection). Happens in distant future (Check, though much of it happens here and now, also). Two protagonists (Check).

No Zelazny, though, though Swanwick is of his peer group among SF writers in age, in  milieu, and in stature in the field.

(And even if this is not right, I do recommend it!)